# Windows Installer does not permit installation from a Remote

Tags: windows, installation, remote-desktop, remote, windows-server-2008-r2

“Windows Installer does not permit installation from a Remote Desktop Connection”

When you try to install an MSI through an RDP connection you could get the “Windows Installer does not permit installation from a Remote Desktop Connection” dialog.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

article [here](http://blog.studiographic.nl/?p=284):

> Everyone seems to think that the `\\tsclient\<drive>` is a regular
>   network share. But it is not! It's a feature of Terminal Services
>   service. However, if you find yourself in the position where you must
>   use the mapped drives for installing software, either copy the
>   software first, or map the `\\tsclient\<drive>` first.
>
> To map run this command:
>
> ```
> net use * \\tsclient\<drive>
> ```
>
> then install from the network mapped drive.. seems the installer does
>   not check the actual path to the mapped drive

Comment: late 2023, using Windows Server 2022: Even with the MSI copied to the C drive, I still get this message. I think the issue is that I'm connected to the machine via RDP in the first place. I have to imagine theres a setting somewhere that allows you to configure this....

Comment: after eleven years this question and answer gives me 100$ per day :D  for ads shown by StackOverflow to visitors ;) ... LOL